# php error "filename cannot be empty, expects parameter 1 to be resource, supplied argument is not a valid stream"

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the following code to upload a csv file usually around 20,000 data into sql server database.

This code very rarely uploads successfully but usually i get the error below :

****Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\file.php on line 37**

**Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\file.php on line 39**

**Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\file.php on line 40****

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) 
{
$filename =$_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
$checkextension = explode(".",$filename);

if($checkextension[1]) == "csv")
{
$filename1 = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
$handle=fopen($filename1,"r");
while($data=fgetcsv($handle,1000000)) { $records = count($data);  } 
fclose($handle);
if($records==15) {
$handle=fopen($filename1,"r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000,",")) !== FALSE) {
$sqlquery = "INSERT into dataupload (date, field1, field2,
field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9,
 field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15)
 values ('$data[0]','$data[1]', '$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]', 
'$data[5]', '$data[6]', '$data[7]', '$data[8]', '$data[9]',
 '$data[10]', '$data[11]', '$data[12]', '$data[13]', '$data[14]')";
 mssql_query($sqlquery); }
 fclose($handle);
 echo "imported successfuly"; } else { echo "--sorry it is not csv file..."; }
  } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary name in `$_FILES['input_name']['tmp_name']` is not the name of the file you sent to the server.

It's a temporary name generated by PHP to make sure it can be stored in the temporary folder without overwriting other files.

`$_FILES['input_name']['name']` should contain the original name.

This is the structure of the `$_FILES` array (when you upload one file only):

```
array(
    'name'     => 'Original file name.ext',
    'type'     => 'mime/type',
    'tmp_name' => 'random_name',
    'error'    => 
        UPLOAD_ERR_OK ||
        UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE ||
        UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE ||
        UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR ||
        UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE ||
        UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION ||
        UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL,
    'size'     => $file['size'][$key],
);
```